# Interactive Bezier curves in VB

Tags: vb.net, graphics, bezier

In preparation for my Fall upcoming Adobe Illustrator class, where students always curse while learning the Pen tool and how to draw Bézier curves, I thought I'd provide them with some "theoretical foundation" outside of Illustrator. So far, I'm able to demonstrate the workings of a curve through four points described by x and y coordinates entered in a separate text boxes (see attached screen capture). My question, how can I "transform" this static demonstration into an interactive one, by allowing the students to "select" control points (shown in blue) and move them around the PictureBox? That's not a simple problem. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Here is my source code so far:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Point1_X, Point1_Y, Point2_X, Point2_Y, Point3_X, Point3_Y, Point4_X, Point4_Y As Integer
Dim LignesDeDirection As Boolean

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    LignesDeDirection = False

    Point1_X = 100
    Point1_Y = 100
    Point2_X = 200
    Point2_Y = 200
    Point3_X = 50
    Point3_Y = 250
    Point4_X = 400
    Point4_Y = 400

    tbPoint1_X.Text = Point1_X
    tbPoint1_Y.Text = Point1_Y
    tbPoint2_X.Text = Point2_X
    tbPoint2_Y.Text = Point2_Y
    tbPoint3_X.Text = Point3_X
    tbPoint3_Y.Text = Point3_Y
    tbPoint4_X.Text = Point4_X
    tbPoint4_Y.Text = Point4_Y

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint

    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.LightGray)
    Dim FondBlanc As New SolidBrush(Color.White)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(FondBlanc, 0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)

    Dim blackPen = New Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128), 1)
    Dim blackPen2pix = New Pen(Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64), 2)
    Dim EllipsePen = New Pen(Color.FromArgb(0, 128, 255), 3)

    Dim blackPen3 = New Pen(Color.Black, 5.0F)
    Dim blackPen2 = New Pen(Color.FromArgb(164, 164, 164), 1)

    Dim CouleurPoint As New SolidBrush(Color.Magenta)
    Dim CouleurControl As New SolidBrush(Color.Blue)
    Dim Color2 = New Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128), 1)

    Dim PenBleu As New Pen(Color.Black, 2.0F)
    PenBleu.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Flat  'PenBleu.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor
    PenBleu.CustomEndCap = New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.AdjustableArrowCap(8, 8)

    Dim point1 As New Point(Point1_X, Point1_Y)
    Dim point2 As New Point(Point2_X, Point2_Y)
    Dim point3 As New Point(Point3_X, Point3_Y)
    Dim point4 As New Point(Point4_X, Point4_Y)

    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(CouleurPoint, Point1_X - 5, Point1_Y - 5, 10, 10)
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(CouleurControl, Point2_X - 5, Point2_Y - 5, 10, 10)
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(CouleurControl, Point3_X - 5, Point3_Y - 5, 10, 10)
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(CouleurPoint, Point4_X - 5, Point4_Y - 5, 10, 10)

    Dim PenDashMagenta As New Pen(Color.Magenta, 1.5F)
    PenDashMagenta.DashStyle = Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash

    Dim PenRéférence As New Pen(Color.ForestGreen, 1.0F)
    If cbDirectionLines.Checked = True Then

        LignesDeDirection = True

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(PenRéférence, Point1_X, Point1_Y, Point2_X, Point2_Y)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(PenRéférence, Point3_X, Point3_Y, Point4_X, Point4_Y)
    Else
        LignesDeDirection = False
    End If

    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(PenDashMagenta, Point1_X - 40, Point1_Y - 40, 80, 80)
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(PenDashMagenta, Point4_X - 40, Point4_Y - 40, 80, 80)

    e.Graphics.DrawBezier(PenBleu, point1, point2, point3, point4)

End Sub

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    Point1_X = tbPoint1_X.Text
    Point1_Y = tbPoint1_Y.Text
    Point2_X = tbPoint2_X.Text
    Point2_Y = tbPoint2_Y.Text
    Point3_X = tbPoint3_X.Text
    Point3_Y = tbPoint3_Y.Text
    Point4_X = tbPoint4_X.Text
    Point4_Y = tbPoint4_Y.Text

    PictureBox1.Invalidate()


End Sub
```

End Class
[image: Screen Capture]

Comment: Just to make sure you know it's there, have you seen https://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/ and the much more elaborate https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo? The web is fairly ubiquitous, and any time you can point someone to a demonstrator page is time you don't need to spend making dedicated tools for students.

Comment: Got it!!! Thanks so much. I will certainly point the student's browser at Jason's excellent web page. In the meantime, I managed to extend my demo program to "three" Bezier anchor points and their associated control points. I sort of have found a way to add some mouse interactivity and that will suffice for my demonstration. What the students never get is the working of the Pen tool and its relationship with the presence of "Control" points. I think I got that down pretty well now. I added some basic discussion of what Tangent lines are which are at the core of Bézier curves. Thanks so much!

Comment: You might also find https://bezier.method.ac useful for students who are having a hard time "getting" control points.